# How to kill a daemon in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, daemon

Note: Before you mark this question as duplicate, please note that I've tried all the solutions that I could get online, but still I'm unable to resolve the problem.

I ran daemon through the following command:

```
rake resque:work QUEUE='*' &
```

It returned me `13031`. Now, I want to kill this daemon, and I've trying the following commands:

```
kill -9 13031
kill 13031
```

Running both commands says: `-bash: kill: (13031) - No such process`, and now I'm stuck. I'm unable to figure out how to kill the daemon.

Comment: `pgrep` for the daemon?

Comment: What about to `pkill -9 rake` or to kill the ruby instance of rake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a possible theory for this.

When you run the application as

```
$ rake resque:work QUEUE='*' &
[1] 13031
```

The application internally does a `fork+exit`, to run in background.

`C` code equivalent of that would be:

```
if(fork()) exit(0);
```

So, the process with `PID==13031` will spawn a child process & exit itself. The child will keep running in background & will be inherited by the init process (PID==1).
You can see if this is the case, press another <kbd>enter</kbd> key after starting the `rake` command. Do you see prints like this?

```
[1]+  Done                 rake resque:work QUEUE='*'
```

Try running `ps` in terminal. That should show the child process PID.
If you `kill` that, the daemon should exit.